# How to iterate through an unordered list and then select the parent div of the list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a list of radiobox select questions that I need to validate.

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <div class="question">Question1
        <ul id="choice11">
             <li><input type=radio name="choice1" value="1" /> </li>
             <li><input type=radio name="choice1" value="2" /> </li>
             <li><input type=radio name="choice1" value="2" /> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="question">Question2
        <ul id="choice">
             <li><input type=radio name="choice2" value="1" /> </li>
             <li><input type=radio name="choice2" value="2" /> </li>
             <li><input type=radio name="choice2" value="3" /> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="question">Question3
        <ul id="choice3">
             <li><input type=radio name="choice3" value="1" /> </li>
             <li><input type=radio name="choice3" value="2" /> </li>
             <li><input type=radio name="choice3" value="3" /> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>            
    
</ul>
```

I want to validate and attach a class called "highlight" to ONLY the div which holds the question that has not been answered. The way I have it set up now it will highlight all the questions when I try to submit a form with only one or two non-selected options.

I am having trouble iterating through the questions and selecting only those questions that are unanswered and call this jQuery statement.

```
 $("li .question").addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: How are you iterating through the elements?

Comment: This may help get you started: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: I think you should check out the revised version of the question. The questions are of the same class. Therefore, i can select the class and highlight all of them when something goes wrong. The iteration part is where I am having trouble. I am not really a jquery person. I only know basic stuff but I am working on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.question').filter(function () {
    return ! $(this).find('input:checked').length;
}).addClass('highlight');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XTDre/

Comment: Cool! I was going to write something similar but in more complicated way)

Comment: return ! $(this).find('input:checked').length;??

Comment: @MESSIAH - `$(this).find('input:checked')` selects any checked radio buttons, and `.length` is the count of the matched set. Negating the count would return true for `0`, and false for any other number. The `filter` will return only those `.question`s for which the function returns true.

Comment: This works perfect thank you. This is very simple and to the point.